# How to model a Messaging/Chatting system in C# with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, messaging

I have a simple question

I'm developping a chat system service but I came across something interesting.

I'm currently operating this way :

First table :

```
[Messages] :
SenderID(user),
RecipientID(user),
Content(string)
```

Of course, everytime a user sends a message to the other user, I add it to the table. But I thought about the fact that If a table has a million lines, it would become a mess

So I thought about another way being :

First Table :

```
[Conversation]
ConversationID,
USER1(user),
USER2(user)
```

Second table :

```
[Messages] in which I have 
ConversationID,
Content(string)
```

So basically, I'm asking, which configuration should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach below should be able to sort you out. This is a good basis for both chat and messaging, where with chat you can poll recent messages from the client side and slap on an intuitive UI.

**Message**

```
Message {
  MessageId,
  FromId, -- Foreign key User.UserId
  ToId, -- Foreign key User.UserId
  Subject, 
  Content,
  Attachment, -- can be null or default to a 0
  DateReceived, -- can be null or default to 1901 or sumin'
  DateRead
  ...
}
```

**User**

```
User {
  UserId
  UserName
  ...
}
```

**Queries**

```
Inbox = Message where ToId = Me.UserId
Sent = Message where FromId = Me.UserId
Conversation = Group by Subject
Attachment = (Simple = Path to attachment file. || Better = DocumentId)
```

**Attachment**

```
Document {
  int DocumentId,
  int DocTypeId,
  virtual DocumentType DocumentType,
  string FileName,
  int UserId,
  string mimeType,
  float fileSize,
  string storagePath,
  int OrganizationId,
  string fileHash,
  string ipAddress,
  DateTime DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Then you run into the issue with group chats. Do you send a message to each recipient of the group or do you create a single message that each recipient has access to?

But we're keeping it simple.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another idea, Store the notion of a "message". Whether it be an email, text, sms or sound file. this is where you would store the message text and or other metadata. Think of the "message" as everything up to releasing the stop talk button on a walkie-talkie to end the transmission and everything up until the start and stop has been stored in the "message". This message could be tied to other messages by the fact that the user was replying to a "message" from a prior party's request to talk.

If you wanted to make the whole relationship easy then you could log the "messages" sent to a user, "inbox" and messages sent from a user, "outbox". This is synonymous with today's messaging mentality.

**Message**

```
MessageID, 
Subject, 
Content 
...
```

**MessageReceived**

```
MessageReceivedID, 
UserID, 
FromUserID, 
MessageID, 
DateReceived, 
DateRead,
```

**MessageSent**

```
MessageSentID, 
UserID, 
MessageID, 
DateSent, 
DeletedStatusID
```

Comment: I think 'MessageReceived, ' should be 'MessageReceivedID, '

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions work for simple messaging. The question here really is if there is ever more than one conversation context of messages that should exist between the same two users.

If two users are always talking within the scope of the same conversational context/history every time they being chatting, your first solution is sufficient. Think of this scenario like a Skype chat. It's just one long conversation over time.

If conversational context changes when they begin chatting (i.e. their chat history never really persists between two different days worth of conversations), solution two makes more sense. Think of this scenario like an email between two users. The next day I could write another email to the same person, but it is a different conversation.

Also for solution two, you would also need to add USER to the second table to track which user sent the message in the conversation:

First Table :

```
[Conversation]
ConversationID,
USER1(user),
USER2(user)
```

Second table :

```
[Messages]
ConversationID,
Content(string)
USER(user)
```

In summary, just because a table would have millions of lines doesn't mean it's not the correct way of doing it. In this case, it just depends on the requirements of your application.